# how to set image in imageview after a definite interval?

Tags: android

i have an image view & an array that contain image URLs .I have to traverse through array & set image in image view after every 3 sec...say at start image in image view whose url is at index zero of array then after 3 sec image view should display image at index 1 of array and so on.Please help

Answer (score 1):

Use this to update your imageview periodically...

```
 Timer timer = null;
 int i = 0;

        imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
            timer = new Timer("TweetCollectorTimer");
                    timer.schedule(updateTask, 6000L, 3000L);//here 6000L is starting //delay and 3000L is periodic delay after starting delay


            private TimerTask updateTask = new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                imgView.setImageResource(photoAry[i]);
                                i++;
                                if (i > 5)
                                {
                                    i = 0;
                                                    }
                            }

                        });
                    }
                };
            int photoAry[] = { R.drawable.photo1, R.drawable.photo2, R.drawable.photo3,
                        R.drawable.photo4, R.drawable.photo5, R.drawable.photo6 };
```

**for  stoping this you can call**

```
timer.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a handler and set the image to the imageView in the handler code.

Comment: Check the above codes may work.
Or you may find a similar solution (but using viewFlipper) over here http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/image-slide-show.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use Timer of specific time period that will repeat the function after time interval.

you can use some code like this:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
int delay = 0; // delay for 0 milliseconds.
int period = 25000; // repeat every 25 seconds.
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new SampleTimerTask(), delay, period);

public class SampleTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //MAKE YOUR LOGIC TO SET IMAGE TO IMAGEVIEW
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ANYRANDOM);
    }
}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: and yes do not forget to cancel the timer at last using "timer.cancel();"

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Handler's postDelayed` function for this purpose. It will run your code with specified delay `on the main UI thread`, so you will be able to `update UI controls`.

```
private int mInterval = 3000; // 3 seconds by default, can be changed later
  private Handler mHandler;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    ...
    mHandler = new Handler();
  }

  Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
      updateYourImageView(); //do whatever you want to do in this fuction.
      mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
    }
  };

  void startRepeatingTask() {
    mStatusChecker.run(); 
  }

  void stopRepeatingTask() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
  }
```